# Rounding up to the multiple of float number in PHP

Tags: php, math, rounding, division

I want to round number to the specific number or to a multiple of them. For integer it is ok, but problem appears when I want round to the multile of float like this example:

Number (or multiple) of `package` I want to round:

> ```
> 2.6
> ```
>
> When I type `1` it should round up to `2.6`
>
> When I type `2,5` it should round up to `2,6`
>
> When I type `3` it should **round up to** `5,2 (2 * 2,6)`

I tried to use `fmod` to check divisibility but it is not working for me.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just divide your number by your base float, round it up to the nearest int, and re-multiply.

psuedo code

```
def round_to_float(base_float,to_round)
    return ceiling(to_round / base_float) * base_float
end
```

example with `3`:

```
ceiling(3.0 / 2.6) * 2.6
ceiling(1.15) * 2.6
2 * 2.6
5.2
```

For multiple checking, you could use `fmod($to_round,$base_float) == 0`, but there will inevitably be floating point inaccuracies and it's not a reliable way to test floats.

To be certain, you should pick a small enough `epsilon` (on the order of machine precision on your computer), and make sure your quotient `to_round/base_float` is within `epsilon` of its `floor`.

putting it all together

```
def round_to_float(base_float,to_round)
    quotient = to_round / base_float
    if (absolute_value(quotient - floor(quotient)) < epsilon)
        return false
    else
        return ceiling(quotient) * base_float
    end
end
```

where epsilon is a really small number.  In theory it should be your machine precision ... usually something like 10^-9.  In practice 10^-4 should be sufficient in most use cases.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to add that I want to check first if my base float is already a multiple of to_round. If true I want to return false, if not: continue your code. How can I do that?

Comment: will $param%$base==0  work... never did mod on a floating point before

Comment: @Orangepill php's `%` only works on ints, iirc.  you'll have to use `fmod($to_round,$base_float)`...although you can't really reliably do this, due to floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: @JustinL So what is the best method for check this when I now my float will allways have max 2 decimals like: 2,24. Thanks

Comment: so basically the test is going to be `ceiling($val/$base)*$base == $val`

Comment: @MichałWiatr The problem is that when you enter, say, 2.24 into a computer, it might actually not be storable as binary and actually be stored as 2.239999999, for example, due to the limitations of your machine's precision.  I edited my answer with a safe way to check.

Comment: @JustinL.Thank you so much!